# Kubectl error: the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am getting below error while trying to apply patch :

```
core@dgoutam22-1-coreos-5760 ~ $ kubectl apply -f ads-central-configuration.yaml
Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply
Error from server (Conflict): error when applying patch:
{"data":{"default":"{\"dedicated_redis_cluster\": {\"nodes\": [{\"host\": \"192.168.1.94\", \"port\": 6379}]}}"},"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"data\":{\"default\":\"{\\\"dedicated_redis_cluster\\\": {\\\"nodes\\\": [{\\\"host\\\": \\\"192.168.1.94\\\", \\\"port\\\": 6379}]}}\"},\"kind\":\"ConfigMap\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"creationTimestamp\":\"2018-06-27T07:19:13Z\",\"labels\":{\"acp-app\":\"acp-discovery-service\",\"version\":\"1\"},\"name\":\"ads-central-configuration\",\"namespace\":\"acp-system\",\"resourceVersion\":\"1109832\",\"selfLink\":\"/api/v1/namespaces/acp-system/configmaps/ads-central-configuration\",\"uid\":\"64901676-79da-11e8-bd65-fa163eaa7a28\"}}\n"},"creationTimestamp":"2018-06-27T07:19:13Z","resourceVersion":"1109832","uid":"64901676-79da-11e8-bd65-fa163eaa7a28"}}
to:
&{0xc4200bb380 0xc420356230 acp-system ads-central-configuration ads-central-configuration.yaml 0xc42000c970 4434 false}
**for: "ads-central-configuration.yaml": Operation cannot be fulfilled on configmaps "ads-central-configuration": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again**
core@dgoutam22-1-coreos-5760 ~ $
```

Comment: Please share the content of .yaml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the issue in my test environment. Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a deployment from <kbd>Kubernetes Engine</kbd> > <kbd>Workloads</kbd> > <kbd>Deploy</kbd>
2. Input your Application Name, Namespace, Labels
3. Select cluster or create new cluster

You are able to view the YAML file here and here is the sample:

```
---
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "nginx-1"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "nginx-1"
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "nginx-1"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "nginx-1"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "nginx"
        image: "nginx:latest"
---
apiVersion: "autoscaling/v2beta1"
kind: "HorizontalPodAutoscaler"
metadata:
  name: "nginx-1-hpa"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "nginx-1"
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: "Deployment"
    name: "nginx-1"
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: "Resource"
    resource:
      name: "cpu"
      targetAverageUtilization: 80
```

After deployment if you go to <kbd>Kubernetes Engine</kbd> > <kbd>Workloads</kbd> > <kbd>nginx-1</kbd> (click on it)

a.) You will get Deployment details (Overview, Details, Revision history, events, YAML)
  b.) click on YAML and copy the content from YAML tab
  c.) create new YAML file and paste the content and save the file
  d.) Now if you run the command `$kubectl apply -f newyamlfile.yaml`, it will shows you the below error:

```
Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply
Error from server (Conflict): error when applying patch:
{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"deployment.kubernetes.io/revision\":\"1\"},\"creationTimestamp\":\"2019-09-17T21:34:39Z\",\"generation\":1,\"labels\":{\"app\":\"nginx-1\"},\"name\":\"nginx-1\",\"namespace\":\"default\",\"resourceVersion\":\"218884\",\"selfLink\":\"/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/nginx-1\",\"uid\":\"f41c5b6f-d992-11e9-9adc-42010a80023b\"},\"spec\":{\"progressDeadlineSeconds\":600,\"replicas\":3,\"revisionHistoryLimit\":10,\"selector\":{\"matchLabels\":{\"app\":\"nginx-1\"}},\"strategy\":{\"rollingUpdate\":{\"maxSurge\":\"25%\",\"maxUnavailable\":\"25%\"},\"type\":\"RollingUpdate\"},\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"creationTimestamp\":null,\"labels\":{\"app\":\"nginx-1\"}},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"image\":\"nginx:latest\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"Always\",\"name\":\"nginx\",\"resources\":{},\"terminationMessagePath\":\"/dev/termination-log\",\"terminationMessagePolicy\":\"File\"}],\"dnsPolicy\":\"ClusterFirst\",\"restartPolicy\":\"Always\",\"schedulerName\":\"default-scheduler\",\"securityContext\":{},\"terminationGracePeriodSeconds\":30}}},\"status\":{\"availableReplicas\":3,\"conditions\":[{\"lastTransitionTime\":\"2019-09-17T21:34:47Z\",\"lastUpdateTime\":\"2019-09-17T21:34:47Z\",\"message\":\"Deployment has minimum availability.\",\"reason\":\"MinimumReplicasAvailable\",\"status\":\"True\",\"type\":\"Available\"},{\"lastTransitionTime\":\"2019-09-17T21:34:39Z\",\"lastUpdateTime\":\"2019-09-17T21:34:47Z\",\"message\":\"ReplicaSet \\\"nginx-1-7b4bb7fbf8\\\" has successfully progressed.\",\"reason\":\"NewReplicaSetAvailable\",\"status\":\"True\",\"type\":\"Progressing\"}],\"observedGeneration\":1,\"readyReplicas\":3,\"replicas\":3,\"updatedReplicas\":3}}\n"},"generation":1,"resourceVersion":"218884"},"spec":{"replicas":3},"status":{"availableReplicas":3,"observedGeneration":1,"readyReplicas":3,"replicas":3,"updatedReplicas":3}}
to:
Resource: "apps/v1, Resource=deployments", GroupVersionKind: "apps/v1, Kind=Deployment"
Name: "nginx-1", Namespace: "default"
Object: &{map["apiVersion":"apps/v1" "metadata":map["name":"nginx-1" "namespace":"default" "selfLink":"/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/nginx-1" "uid":"f41c5b6f-d992-11e9-9adc-42010a80023b" "generation":'\x02' "labels":map["app":"nginx-1"] "annotations":map["deployment.kubernetes.io/revision":"1"] "resourceVersion":"219951" "creationTimestamp":"2019-09-17T21:34:39Z"] "spec":map["replicas":'\x01' "selector":map["matchLabels":map["app":"nginx-1"]] "template":map["metadata":map["labels":map["app":"nginx-1"] "creationTimestamp":<nil>] "spec":map["containers":[map["imagePullPolicy":"Always" "name":"nginx" "image":"nginx:latest" "resources":map[] "terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log" "terminationMessagePolicy":"File"]] "restartPolicy":"Always" "terminationGracePeriodSeconds":'\x1e' "dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst" "securityContext":map[] "schedulerName":"default-scheduler"]] "strategy":map["type":"RollingUpdate" "rollingUpdate":map["maxUnavailable":"25%" "maxSurge":"25%"]] "revisionHistoryLimit":'\n' "progressDeadlineSeconds":'\u0258'] "status":map["observedGeneration":'\x02' "replicas":'\x01' "updatedReplicas":'\x01' "readyReplicas":'\x01' "availableReplicas":'\x01' "conditions":[map["message":"Deployment has minimum availability." "type":"Available" "status":"True" "lastUpdateTime":"2019-09-17T21:34:47Z" "lastTransitionTime":"2019-09-17T21:34:47Z" "reason":"MinimumReplicasAvailable"] map["lastTransitionTime":"2019-09-17T21:34:39Z" "reason":"NewReplicaSetAvailable" "message":"ReplicaSet \"nginx-1-7b4bb7fbf8\" has successfully progressed." "type":"Progressing" "status":"True" "lastUpdateTime":"2019-09-17T21:34:47Z"]]] "kind":"Deployment"]}
for: "test.yaml": Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.apps "nginx-1": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

To solve the problem, you need to find the exact yaml file and then edit it as per your requirement, after that you can run `$kubectl apply -f nginx-1.yaml`

Hope this information finds you well.

Answer (score 95):

It seems likely that your yaml configurations were copy pasted from what was generated, and thus contains fields such as `creationTimestamp` (and `resourceVersion`, `selfLink`, and `uid`), which don't belong in a declarative configuration file.

Go through your yaml and clean it up.  Remove things that are instance specific.  Your final yaml should be simple enough that you can easily understand it.

Answer (score 55):

Remove these lines from the file:

```
  creationTimestamp:   
  resourceVersion:  
  selfLink:   
  uid:
```

Then try to apply again.

Answer (score 6):

you may have been edited the same exported deployment file..

1 - try to reexport it with:

```
kubectl get deployment <DEPLOYMENT-NAME> -o yaml > deployment-file.yaml
```

2 - make the needed modifications in "deployment-file.yaml"

3 - apply the changes with:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment-file.yaml
```

**OR:**

you may want to edit the deployment directly.. use :

`kubectl edit deployment <DEPLOYMENT-NAME> -o yaml`

change the default editor if you aren't familiar with VI editor : `export EDITOR=nano`

Answer (score 6):

Give attention to put the last `resourceVersion` in your update, you can get it running:

```sh
kubectl get deployment <DEPLOYMENT-NAME> -o yaml | grep resourceVersion
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is coming because the deployment.yaml has an entry for resourceVersion. Remove it as it's not needed and you will be able to apply the new configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I encountred this error when trying to apply a new Kubernetes secret to override an existing secret for an old Kubernetes cluster.

When I applied the new Kubernetes secret I got the warning below:

> Warning: resource secrets/myapp-tls is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
> secret/myapp-tls configured

And when I checked the Kubernetes cluster I saw the error:

> Failed to update endpoint  Operation cannot be fulfilled on endpoints the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again

**Here's how I solved it**:

Obviously the issue was because the secret file contains fields such as `creationTimestamp` (and `resourceVersion`, `selfLink`, and `uid`), which don't belong in a declarative configuration file, just like [Roman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659296/10907864) stated above.

For a quick fix, I simply deleted the existing/old Kubernetes secret and reapplied the new one. This time it worked fine.