# kubernetes: Failed to update endpoints warning

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

Here is something I noticed in my `kubectl get events` output

```
Warning   FailedToUpdateEndpoint   Endpoints                 Failed to update endpoint mynamespace/myservice: Operation cannot be fulfilled on endpoints "myservice": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

I am aware of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297136/kubectl-error-the-object-has-been-modified-please-apply-your-changes-to-the-la), but I do not think is applicable, given I am not explicitly creating an `Endpoint` resource via `yaml`.

I am noticing some minor service unavailability during image updates so I am trying to check if this is related.

Using GKE with version `v1.12.7-gke.25` on both masters and nodes, on top of `istio`.

Comment: So K8s api server works on eventual consistency , if more than 1 controllers are trying to modify the same resources. one of them will get this error,  as endpoint is managed by few controllers such as endpoint controllers, kube-proxy, service controllers

Comment: thanks. so it is something that can be safely ignored?

Comment: yea, it's perfectly fine. I have provided bunch of statement with links.

Comment: restart the node, problem resolved.  v1.21.2

Comment: Numero Uno pain in the butt with Kube right here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's common behaviour of **k8s** to let the k8s clients (Controllers) know to try again.

> Kubernetes leverages the concept of resource versions to achieve **optimistic concurrency.** [concurrency-control-and-consistency](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#concurrency-control-and-consistency)

It's populated by the system.

> To enable clients to build a model of the current state of a cluster, all Kubernetes object resource types are required to support consistent lists and an incremental change notification feed called a watch. Every Kubernetes object has a resourceVersion field representing the version of that resource as stored in the underlying database. When retrieving a collection of resources (either namespace or cluster scoped), the response from the server will contain a resourceVersion value that can be used to initiate a watch against the server. The server will return all changes (creates, deletes, and updates) that occur after the supplied resourceVersion. This allows a client to fetch the current state and then watch for changes without missing any updates. If the client watch is disconnected they can restart a new watch from the last returned resourceVersion, or perform a new collection request and begin again [efficient-detection-of-changes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes)

Comment: Best answer I have seen yet to this perplexing problem. Thanks!