# error with dry-run on the server in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

With:

`kubectl apply -f web.yaml --server-dry-run --validate=false -o yaml`

I get an error:

```
Error: unknown flag: --server-dry-run
See 'kubectl apply --help' for usage.
```

And even with:

`kubectl apply -f web.yaml --dry-run=server --validate=false -o yaml`

I get another error:

```
Warning: resource deployments/web is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
Error from server (Conflict): error when applying patch:
{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"creationTimestamp\":\"2021-12-30T08:51:06Z\",\"generation\":1,\"labels\":{\"app\":\"web\"},\"name\":\"web\",\"namespace\":\"default\",\"resourceVersion\":\"1589\",\"uid\":\"c2a4c20e-f55b-4113-b8e6-d2c19bb3e91c\"},\"spec\":{\"progressDeadlineSeconds\":600,\"replicas\":1,\"revisionHistoryLimit\":10,\"selector\":{\"matchLabels\":{\"app\":\"web\"}},\"strategy\":{\"rollingUpdate\":{\"maxSurge\":\"25%\",\"maxUnavailable\":\"25%\"},\"type\":\"RollingUpdate\"},\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"creationTimestamp\":null,\"labels\":{\"app\":\"web\"}},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"image\":\"nginx\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"Always\",\"name\":\"nginx\",\"resources\":{},\"terminationMessagePath\":\"/dev/termination-log\",\"terminationMessagePolicy\":\"File\"}],\"dnsPolicy\":\"ClusterFirst\",\"restartPolicy\":\"Always\",\"schedulerName\":\"default-scheduler\",\"securityContext\":{},\"terminationGracePeriodSeconds\":30}}},\"status\":{}}\n"},"resourceVersion":"1589"}}
to:
Resource: "apps/v1, Resource=deployments", GroupVersionKind: "apps/v1, Kind=Deployment"
Name: "web", Namespace: "default"
for: "web.yaml": Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.apps "web": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

What should I do?

I'm using docker-desktop and my kubectl version is:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.4", GitCommit:"b695d79d4f967c403a96986f1750a35eb75e75f1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-17T15:48:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.4", GitCommit:"b695d79d4f967c403a96986f1750a35eb75e75f1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-17T15:42:41Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

and my cluster version is `1.22.4`

Comment: Please specify the version of kubectl and Kubernetes Cluster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I get an error:

```yaml
Error: unknown flag: --server-dry-run
See 'kubectl apply --help' for usage.
```

That's correct. This flag is deprecated. You need to use `--dry-run=server` flag. For more look [at this site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#create).

As for the second problem, it seems that this is correct on the part of k8s. You can find the [explanation here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/84430#issuecomment-638376994). If you want to resolve your problem you need to remove fields `creationTimestamp`. It is well explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297136/kubectl-error-the-object-has-been-modified-please-apply-your-changes-to-the-la).

Comment: Thank you so much... it works now like a champ...